# Jenkins Pipeline job can't find script due to @tmp path being created

Tags: git, bash, jenkins, groovy

I am writing a pipeline job that will call another script to execute. The Jenkinsfile and script exist in the same directory and yet the job fails to find the script to run.

This is the relevant bit of script;

```
stage ('Update') {
    try {
        dir('jenkins/pipeline/update-jenkins-plugins-ppln') {
            sh 'ls -l'
            sh 'update-plugins.sh'
        }
}
```

which returns the following error;

```
[update-jenkins-plugins-ppln] Running shell script
+ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 2441 Dec 20 09:34 Jenkinsfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins  506 Dec 19 14:06 update-plugins.sh
[Pipeline] sh
[update-jenkins-plugins-ppln] Running shell script
+ update-plugins.sh
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/update-jenkins-plugins-ppln/jenkins/pipeline/update-jenkins-plugins-ppln@tmp/durable-11cefdd0/script.sh: 2: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/update-jenkins-plugins-ppln/jenkins/pipeline/update-jenkins-plugins-ppln@tmp/durable-11cefdd0/script.sh: update-plugins.sh: not found
```

As you can see, the pathing I'm using is correct because according to the `ls` the file I need `update-plugins.sh` is in the directory I've pathed to. For some reason though, when actually searching for the script Jenkins is adding `@tmp/durable-8d48734f/script.sh` onto the path.

Various troubleshooting:

- I read that you have to checkout the branch again even if you're already checking it out to get the Jenkinsfile, so I am.
- I have ssh'd into the Jenkins box to check and yes, the script is there.

Why is Jenkins adding the @tmp bit, and is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Hi. Just wondering if you found a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Phil Nope, it's still an issue

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the jenkins workspace environment variable `WORKSPACE` (absolute path of the workspace)? With that your line would look something like this:

```
sh '${WORKSPACE}/jenkins/pipeline/update-jenkins-plugins-ppln/update-plugins.sh'
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess your pwd is not in PATH so you have to call it like this: `sh './update-plugins.sh'`

Comment: Tried that already; same error `+ ./update-plugins.sh
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/update-jenkins-plugins-ppln@tmp/durable-88ee0ed4/script.sh: 2: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/update-jenkins-plugins-ppln@tmp/durable-88ee0ed4/script.sh: ./update-plugins.sh: not found`

Comment: Then that's strange. I can only suggest you to try sh ' bash update-plugins.sh' or to calculate full path using pipeline func pwd(), concatenate and call the script by absolute path.

Comment: For me it worked using './' in the beginning of the script's name.

Comment: For we adding of './' also worked. I think it may depend on the version of plugins and/or Jenkins. I use Jenkins 2.164.3, Pipeline Plugin 2.6, Durable Task Plugin 1.29.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I think @Oren technically answered your question about *why* Jenkins creates this `tmp` space, but I can share some info about how I solved it.

Basically, my Jenkins host symlinks `bin/sh` to `dash`; not `bash`. So, using a POSIX-compliant shell script solved the issue for me.

For example, I was trying to use `shopt -s extglob` to do some pattern matching:

```
stage {
    def shellCommand = $/ "rm -rf ! (_data|_includes|_plugins|Gemfile|_config.yml|page-builder)"/$
    sh(returnStdout: true, script: shellCommand).trim()
}
```

Since `dash` doesn't support `extglob`, replacing that with a POSIX-compliant `find` command worked:

```
stage {
    sh('find . -regextype posix-extended -not -regex ".*includes.*|.*data.*|.*plugins.*|.*config.yml|.*Gemfile.*"')
}
```

Comment: Yes, `/bin/sh -> /bin/dash` in my case

Answer (score 0):

The @tmp folder is there for jenkins job and stages statistics (duration of stages, etc), you can delete it if you want to be sure. I assume that your kind of issue is related for wrong path, double check it.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this particular case has nothing to do with Jenkins pipelines, since it can be reproduced outside the Jenkins in the console. Once I got this issue due to **DOS line-endings** in my script which I ran in a pipeline's "sh()". Look at this example:

```
$ cat -v dos_formatted.sh
#! /bin/sh^M
pwd^M

$ cat script.sh
./dos_formatted.sh

$ sh -xe script.sh
+ ./dos_formatted.sh
script.sh: 1: script.sh: ./dos_formatted.sh: not found
```

It illustrates well that the "not found" message is misleading. The script is on the right place and the permissions are sufficient, but when you run it from another script it fails with such an error message.

The code of the Durable Task Plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/durable-task-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/durabletask/BourneShellScript.java) shows that the plugin runs the auto-generated script.sh as "sh -xe ...", therefore it's exactly our case.

The above described situation can happen if you "git clone" some (probably 3rd party) Git project and don't make sure that is was cloned with Unix-style LF.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue where though the shell script is present on path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/New_commit_test/Fibonacci.sh, Jenkins build was getting failed with error message : "/tmp/jenkins6688065235543884785.sh: 3: /tmp/jenkins6688065235543884785.sh: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/New_commit_test/Fibonacci.sh: not found"

so i changed my earlier command from :
${WORKSPACE}/Fibonacci.sh > New_commit_test.txt

to : (since i was using bash script here )
**bash** ${WORKSPACE}/Fibonacci.sh > New_commit_test.txt

which sorted issue here for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Adding "bin/bash" to the "Shell Executable" option under "Manage Jenkins -> Configure System" solved it.

I also though it was some pathing issue, but Jenkins couldn't find the bash executable itself, although the errors lead to believe otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I had more or less the same issue as others described here, in a sense closer to @AlexanderSamoylov case, so far as Jenkins could not resolve `#!` interpreter i.e. the Shell executable.

In my case, I had this function

```
def skipCi() {
    sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''#!/bin/bash +x
    git log -1 --oneline
    ''') =~ /(ci-skip|skip-ci)/
}
```

I had copied this from one *succesful* Jenkinsfile to another.

At some point later, I started using a Docker agent i.e. `golang:1.16-alpine` in the new project/Jenkinsfile and all of a sudden the it stopped working:

```
sh: /home/ec2-user/workspace/terraform-provider-blah-blah_master@2@tmp/durable-a16f34fc/script.sh: not found
```

There is nothing in this error that states:

> You are using `#!/bin/bash` as the shell interpreter within you `skipCi()` function, but unfortunately for you, you've used this function in a *when* clause for a stage that you are running in a *Docker* agent using the `golang:1.16-alpine` image... which DOES NOT ship with `bash`.
> Poor you.

I don't think this is solvable by @LeonHeld's solution, as the check is run within an image - it needs to, as it needs to `git log` after the checkout - so installing Bash in Jenkins/on the node likely won't have an affect.

Answer (score 0):

was facing this issue with helm

the solution was to use full path "/usr/local/bin/helm"

you can find the full path of helm in linux by using "which helm"