# Pipeline script tries creating file in @2 workspace

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

For below groovy  code:

```
node('worker_node'){

    ws("${WORKSPACE}"){
        createPropertiesFile()    
    }

}


def createPropertiesFile(){

    try{
        sh 'whoami'    
        def newFile = new File("sonar-project.properties")
        newFile.createNewFile()
    }catch(Throwable e){

        echo "${e}"
    }
}
```

---

Two work spaces are created:

```
/app/jenkins/workspace/Test/groovy_closures on worker_node
/app/jenkins/workspace/Test/groovy_closures@2 on worker_node // not sure about the purpose of this work space
```

---

but gives below output:

```
Running on worker_node in /app/jenkins/workspace/Test/groovy_closures
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] ws
Running in /app/jenkins/workspace/Test/groovy_closures@2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ whoami
jenkins
[Pipeline] echo
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // ws
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

---

`$ whoami` gives `jenkins` in terms of owner to run this script, as shown below:

[User_Jenkins_configuration_on_worker_node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhgae.png)

---

```
ws("${WORKSPACE}"){
  sh "touch file" // creates file in /app/jenkins/workspace/Test/groovy_closures@2 folder but not in /app/jenkins/workspace/Test/groovy_closures folder
}
```

---

1) Why user `jenkins` has no permission to create a file? How to configure user `jenkins` to get this permission, in Jenkins?

2) How to create a file in `/app/jenkins/workspace/Test/groovy_closures` but not in `/app/jenkins/workspace/Test/groovy_closures@2`?

Comment: How did you setup your jenkins agent?

Comment: @JustAProgrammer sorry.. somebody else  the setup. Do you have any question on creation on @2 folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41246161/11115740

Comment: @JustAProgrammer Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: Did you create a service for it or simply run it locally (the .jar)? If you created a user just for the jenkins agent then maybe this causes the problem with the permissions.

Comment: @JustAProgrammer Query edited with required info

Comment: @JustAProgrammer Jenkins plugn has the `sonar-scanner.properties` file with owner jenkins `-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins 319 Jan  8 12:17 /app/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/maven_install/conf/sonar-scanner.properties`